# Getting API error [9000] desc [Error in service CCA lookup] for Amex in cardinalcommerce

Tags: php, jwt, 3d-secure

I am using Cardinal Cruise Hybrid for 3D secure. I followed the documentation provided by[Cardinal Cruise](https://developer.cardinalcommerce.com/Cardinal-Cruise-Hybrid/). 
I have created JWT with PHP. I am using [Cardinal Cruise Javascript Activation Credentials](https://developer.cardinalcommerce.com/try-it-now.shtml). I am getting cmpi_lookup response and cmpi_authenticate response with Visa and master.

I am unable to get cmpi_lookup response with Amex card. Can any one help me to fix this issue?
My js code

```
  Cardinal.configure({
logging: {
    level: "on"
}
  });

  var orderObject =  {
        "Authorization": {
          "AuthorizeAccount": true
        },
        "Cart": [
          {
            "Name": "test",
            "SKU": "sdsadsf",
            "Quantity": "3",
            "Description": "ccccc"
          }
        ],
        "Consumer": {
          "Email1": "test@mail.com",
          "Email2": "test1@mail.com",
          "ShippingAddress": {
            "FullName": "John Smith",
            "FirstName": "John",
            "MiddleName": "",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "Address1": "8100 Tyler Blvd.",
            "Address2": "",
            "Address3": "",
            "City": "Mentor",
            "State": "Ohio",
            "PostalCode": "44060",
            "CountryCode": "US",
            "Phone1": "",
            "Phone2": ""
          },
          "BillingAddress": {
            "FullName": "John Smith",
            "FirstName": "John",
            "MiddleName": "",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "Address1": "8100 Tyler Blvd.",
            "Address2": "",
            "Address3": "",
            "City": "Mentor",
            "State": "Ohio",
            "PostalCode": "44060",
            "CountryCode": "US",
            "Phone1": "",
            "Phone2": ""
          },
          "Account": {
            "AccountNumber": 340000000003961,
            "ExpirationMonth": 01,
            "ExpirationYear": 2022,
            "CardCode": 0775,
            "NameOnAccount": "John Smith"
          }
        },
        "Options": {
          "EnableCCA": true
        },
        "OrderDetails": { 
          "OrderNumber": Math.random(0, 1000000) + "-shzs",
          "Amount": 25.00,
          "CurrencyCode": "840",
          "OrderDescription": "nothg",
          "OrderChannel": "S",
          "TransactionId": "2fDSaySnCmDGCjPglzqX"
        },
        "Token": {
         "Token": "",
          "CardCode": 0775,
          "ExpirationMonth": 01,
          "ExpirationYear": 2022
        },
         "CCAExtension" : {
            "AcquirerId" : "",
            "AcquirerMerchantId" : "",
            "AcquirerPassword" : "",
            "CountryCodeOverride" : "US",
            "FormId" : "",
            "MerchantName" : "devCenterMerchant",
            "MerchantUrl" : "https://centineltest.cardinalcommerce.com/maps/txns.asp",
            "PAResPayload" : "",
            "ProductCode" : "01",
            "ShippingMethod" : "01"
        }
  };

  Cardinal.setup('init', {
    jwt: document.getElementById('JWTContainer').value,
    order: orderObject
  });
  Cardinal.on('payments.setupComplete', function(){ 
  Cardinal.start('cca', orderObject); 
  });
```

Getting response

```
ActionCode: "NOACTION"
ErrorDescription: "Error in service CCA lookup"
ErrorNumber: 9000
ECIFlag: "07"
Enrolled: "U"
```

Comment: Hello there, did you ever resolve this issue?  I am also trying to integrate Cardinal Cruise into our Paypal backend and encountering the same issue?

Comment: @Rob, i didn't solve this issue. EciFlag 7 - 'Non 3-D Secure Transaction',
Enrolled U - Unavailable - The DS or ACS is not available for authentication at the time of the request. Given cardinal amex test card number doesn't support for 3-D secure transaction.

Comment: Try the doco here: https://cruisecontrolsbox.cardinalcommerce.com/getting-started.html

Comment: I hit the same issue, and the cause was using a decimal point in the "OrderDetails"  > "Amount" field. This is prohibited according to the docs, and caused this exact (very unhelpful!) error message.

Comment: For those Googling for an answer 
"Amount": 25.00 is wrong it should be "Amount": 2500 with no decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me temporarily but, still have other blockers

```
const orderObj = {
OrderDetails: {
  Amount: '2000',
  CurrencyCode: "NGN"
},
Consumer: {
  DFReferenceId: ReferenceId,
  Account: {
    AccountNumber: '4000000000001091',
    ExpirationMonth: '01',
    ExpirationYear: '2022',
    CardCode: '111'
  },
}
}
Cardinal.trigger("bin.process", `${fields.card}`)
.then(function (result) {
 if (result.Status) {
  Cardinal.start('cca', orderObj);
 }
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error, '===== bin.process error log');
  // An error occurred during profiling
})
```